# PostgreSQL: restore data only if not exist

Tags: postgresql, cmd, pg-dump, postgresql-12, pg-restore

I am dumping the data of a table into a .tar file and restoring it into the same table on a different database.

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\pg_dump.exe --file "C:\\SQL_ST~1\\pg_dump.tar" --host "localhost" --port "5432" --username "postgres" --no-password --verbose --format=c --blobs --data-only --table "runtime.batches" "sdm_kunde"
```

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\pg_restore.exe --host "localhost" --port "5432" --username "postgres" --no-password --dbname "sdm_wir" --data-only --verbose --schema "runtime" --table "batches" "C:\\SQL_ST~1\\pg_dump.tar"
```

The problem is that the databases have almost identical information stored inside them, which conflicts with the restore due to the unique restraint on one of the columns. Is there a way to only restore data if it doesn't exist in the target database?

Comment: One thing is for sure; ```C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\pg_dump.exe``` should be either ```"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\pg_dump.exe"```, or ```"%ProgramFiles%\PostgreSQL\12\bin\pg_dump.exe"```. The doublequotes are necessary because of the space in the file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a primary key or unique constraint on your tables that will identify the duplicates, you can

```bash
pg_dump --format=custom --inserts --on-conflict-do-nothing --data-only --blobs --table=mytab mydb
```

Restoring that dump will silently skip rows that are already in the target table. Note that large objects will be unconditionally replaced — but then, you shouldn't be using large objects anyway.

Comment: It works great, thank you!